# Javascript: split array into multiple arrays by value

Tags: javascript, arrays, split

For example I have an array:

```
const array= ['a', 'X', 'c', 'X', 'e', 'f', 'X']
```

And I want to split the array at each point where the element = `X`, so I should have 6 arrays afterwards:

```
['a'],
['X'],
['c'],
['X'],
['e', 'f'],
['X']
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would you want to do this?

Comment: _"I couldn't make it work"_  what did you try? Perhaps we can help with that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there's a character (or sequence of characters) (e.g. for the purpose of my demo code, `#`) that will not occur in the values, you can `join` the array using that character sequnce, then `split` on `X` (using a regex with capture group to retain the `X` values) and then `split` on the character sequence again:

```js
const array = ['a', 'b', 'X', 'cd', 'X', 'e', 'f', 'X']

let out = array
  .join('#')                     // merge into a string
  .split(/(?:^|#)(X)(?:#|$)/)    // split on X (but retain them)
  .filter(Boolean)               // remove empty values
  .map(v => v.split('#'));       // split on #

console.log(out);
```

Comment: You don't really need the join character (`#`). Joining on an empty string has the same result without having to worry about picking something that doesn't appear in the array

Comment: Eg `array.join('').split(/(X)/).filter(Boolean).map(s => [...s])`

Comment: @Phil the reason I went with a join character was in case the values were actually longer than just one character; if the array is actually `['ab', 'X', 'cd', 'X', 'e', 'f', 'X']` then without the join character you get `[ [ "a", "b" ], [ "X" ], [ "c", "d" ], [ "X" ], [ "e", "f" ], [ "X" ] ]`

Comment: Isn't that what OP wants?

Comment: I don't think so, I think individual array elements are meant to stay as they were, i.e. the result for that input should be `[ [ "ab" ], [ "X" ], [ "cd" ], [ "X" ], [ "e", "f" ], [ "X" ] ]` because we're just splitting the array up, not the individual elements.

Comment: clever solution.  fyi, if it's necessary to split on "XX" or "" or other edge cases `.split(/#(X)(?:#|$)/)` can make it work.  You can even avoid having to filter out blanks.

Comment: Thanks Nick, the output is what I need

Comment: @pangpp that's good. To be honest though, I think you might find one of the other solutions to be more reliable and I would definitely recommend taking a look at them.

Comment: @user120242 sleeping on it helped me see your point. I've updated the code accordingly (note it needed `(?:^|#)` instead of `#` in case an `X` was the first entry in the array)

Comment: @pangpp I've made an edit to the answer that makes an improvement in the code and helps avoid a couple of edge cases that might have been problematic.

Answer (score 1):

indexOf starting from last found X position to get chunk, push sliced chunks and ['X']

```js
let array = ['a', 'X', 'c', 'X', 'e', 'f', 'X']

const chunkX = array => {
  if(!array.length) return array

  let i = 0, j
  const arr = []
  while((j = array.indexOf('X',i)) !== -1) {
    // i!==j to prevent generating blank array when two consecutive 'X's
    i!==j && arr.push(array.slice(i,j))
    arr.push([array[j]])
    i = j + 1
  }
  if(i < array.length) arr.push(array.slice(i))

  return arr
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(chunkX(array)))

// additional test cases that were failing
array = ['a','X','b','X','X','X','X', 'c', 'X', 'e', 'f', 'X', 'g']
console.log(JSON.stringify(chunkX(array)))

array = ['X','X','a','X','b','X','XX','X', 'c', 'X', 'e', 'f', 'X', 'g', 'X']
console.log(JSON.stringify(chunkX(array)))

array = ['X']
console.log(JSON.stringify(chunkX(array)))
```

Answer (score 1):

use the temporary `window` to maintain the items in between separator.

```js
const array = ["a", "X", "c", "X", "e", "f", "X", "n"];

const split = (arr, sep) => {
  const output = [];
  const win = [];
  arr.forEach((item) => {
    if (item === sep) {
      output.push([...win], [item]);
      win.length = 0;
    } else {
      win.push(item);
    }
  });
  if (win.length > 0) {
    output.push([...win]);
  }
  return output;
};

console.log(split(array, "X"));
```