# JavaScript - how to split an array based on separator values

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I have an array of strings in JavaScript and I want to split them into "paragraphs" by grouping them together based on blank lines. for instance:

`["a", "b", "", "c", "", "d", "e", "f"]` => `[["a", "b"], ["c"], ["d", "e", "f"]]`

It's exactly like `string.split()` but with an array as the input instead of a string.

Of course, I could write this function myself using a loop or maybe reduce but it sounds like quite a generic function. I'm wondering if there is anything in lodash or similar that could do it.

Comment: A quick search brought (possible) solutions for this topic here on SO... -> [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this on your own?

Comment: @Andreas maybe you missed the part `...Of course I could write this function myself...I'm wondering if there is anything in lodash or similar that could do it.`

Comment: @Ergis SO is not a free _"I need XYZ, find a solution for me"_ service

Comment: @Andreas He is literally just asking if there is something in `lodash` for it. If someone has that information, he could share. Otherwise, this could end-up as an issue for a 'feature' in lodash's github. So why do you have totake it so hard?

Comment: @Andreas I searched lodash, stackoverflow, underscore and npmjs. most of the solutions were splitting into fixed size chunks but I couldn't find anything about splitting based on some condition to detect a delimiter. Of course I could write it myself and not share it with anyone but if we all did that then we wouldn't have useful libraries like lodash and resources like SO

Comment: _"I couldn't find anything about splitting based on some condition"_ - [Splitting array based on values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16018407/splitting-array-based-on-values), [Javascript: split array into multiple arrays by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62274609/javascript-split-array-into-multiple-arrays-by-value), ...

Answer (score 2):

you mean like this ?

```js
let data = ["a", "b", "", "c", "", "d", "e", "f"]
let temp = []
let result = []
data.map(x => {  
  if(x) {
    temp.push(x)
  } else {
    result.push(temp)
    temp = []
  }
})

temp.length != 0 ? result.push(temp) : '' 
console.log(result)
```

Comment: *Of course I could write this function myself using a loop or maybe reduce but it sounds like quite a generic function. I'm wondering if there is anything in lodash or similar that could do it.* How does your answer relate to what is being asked?

Comment: Not generic enough.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure `lodash` can resolve it at this time.

In the meanwhile, you can do the trick in this way

```js
const array = ["a", "b", "", "c", "", "d", "e", "f"];
const delimiter = ",";
var index = 0;

const result = array.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  if(curr == "") index++;
  else acc[index] = (acc[index] || "") + delimiter + curr;
  
  return acc;
}, [])
console.log(result.map(r => r.substring(1).split(delimiter)));
```

Comment: Not my DV but if you're not going to post an answer with lodash then vote to close as one of the duplicates you can find here on SO.

Comment: IMO, this question is quite useful (Except the IO didn't provide effort/what tried so far). Hopefully, `lodash` will have the solution soon in this case. So that is the reason why I still wanna answer @Andreas

Comment: This is not a generic solution. It doesn't even work for strings - try with `["a", b", "", "c,d",]` and you get the second group as `["c", "d"]`. Adjusting the delimiter doesn't help much as it might still clash with the data. Further problem is if the data is not a string: `[1, 2, "", 3, 4]` will have the data types changed by this. having objects will just fail even worse. Ultimately *splitting* is fundamentally flawed approach and not suitable as a generic solution.

Comment: _"IMO, this question is quite useful..."_ - That might be the case, but this doesn't change the fact that there are already suitable other questions/answers hence this should be closed as duplicate.

Comment: @Andreas please report the question as a duplicate and link to one or more of the solutions you already found. the only solution I found was for swift, not JS

Comment: I don't think the content items in the array having `"c,d"`. Besides, the answer based on sample data of OP. Once again, I hope that `lodash` will have the solution soon in this case.

Comment: Yeah. I'm voting to close this question but still leave my answer here. @Andreas

Comment: _"...but still leave my answer here"_ - Not losing that sweet reputation...

Answer (score -1):

If it's a simple formula that doesn't use loops, you can create it like this:

```
arr.map(v => v || ",").join("").split(",").map(v => v.split(""))
```

If you plan on getting paragraphs values a lot, you might want to define a function for it.

First, put this in your code somewhere:

```
Array.prototype.paragraphs = function(){
  return this.map(v => v || ",").join("").split(",").map(v => v.split(""))
}
```

Now:

```
["a", "b", "", "c", "", "d", "e", "f"].paragraphs()
```

Comment: [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)